# Progress Bar Remains At 0%

Tags: android

I have tried to implement Async to handle the background unzipping of files with a progresbar however the unzip is happening while the progressbar displays 0%, after the unzipping the progresbar dismisses at 0%.. the onProgressUpdate method is not updating. my code below:

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    System.out.println("DIALOG:");
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: //
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Extracting. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;   
    default:
        return null;
    }
    }

            private void fileZ() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String zipFile = myDEST + myFolderImages + myFILEposterZIP;             
                    String unzipLocation = myDEST + myFolderImages; 

                    Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation); 
                    d.unzip();
                        System.out.println("UNZIPPING");
                }

            class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        fileZ();
                        return null;
                    }

                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

                    // setting progress percentage
                    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
                dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            }

            }
}
```

Edit #1:

```
class ExtractFiles extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Thread thread = new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            int prog = 0;
                             while(prog < 100)
                             {

                                 pDialog.setProgress(prog);
                                 try {
                                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                 prog ++;
                             }
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();

                    System.out.println("EXTRACTING...");
                    fileZ();

                    return null;
                }
```

Comment: Have you coded for progress bar update??

Comment: No, I thought it would do that calculation based on the doInBackground process, I am not sure how to update the onProgressUpdate

Comment: Please see Edit #1, the progress bar ends at 21% after the extraction.. it miscalculates

Answer (score 0):

You don't update correctly your progress bar while you unzip the file..

Use a counter like :

```
count++;
```

and update progressbar..

```
publishProgress((int)((count));
```